# Thai pronunciation symbols and rules on IPA

Tags: orthography, pronunciation, ipa, thai

Where can I find a set of IPA symbols for Thai language pronunciation and its rules? I know IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) was mainly created to represent the differences in sounds of words spoken in European and other English-speaking countries, but was wondering whether seeing wan IPA chat our something similar for Thai pronunciation could prove useful when learning Thai, and where to find such information.Thanks.

Finally, I'm looking for a page where I can actually hear the sound of these symbols so that I can hear and not just read them. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Note that this question is far too language-specific; such questions are discouraged at Linguistics.SE; (2) IPA works fine not only for European languages; (3) What have you found so far? Have you seen the Wikipedia articles for [Thai language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_language) and [Thai alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_alphabet)?

Comment: (4) Answering your another question, I referenced a great resource. Have you checked it? There you may find a large dictionary with ability to hear the sound; Also, Google Translate's pronunciation of Thai is great (unlike the written transcription, as I said). (5) Don't focus reading individual sounds, this leads to mistakes while learning. Rather listen to complete words. They are often consist of 2-3 syllables, easily determinable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. These address my questions quite well. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but relating to your 4th point, are you saying that Thai has spelling artifacts like are present in English, where, pronunciation cannot always be predicted by spelling or at least not unless one is really good at it? This would mean both monolingual and bilingual Thai dictionaries would provide pronunciation separately from word spelling. If this is the case, what system of pronunciation would such dictionaries use and could you recommend a few good ones? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. the (1) problem is consonant reduplication. For example, the name of Pattaya town is written `พัทยา`, and a learner would syllabify it `พัท-ยา`. However, the correct syllabification is `พัท-ทะ-ยา`, nothing in the written form suggests there is the middle syllable. Check [this article](http://www.thai-language.com/ref/glossary#svarabhakti). Yet (2) problem is the opposite: unread syllables (besides those marked with Karan symbol which ultimately tells to skip a syllable). For example Suwarnabhumi airport is pronounced `[su wan na phum]` (not `-mi`). Grammatically, it ends with `-mi`.

Comment: So, every time when the word is read other than grammar suggests, all dictionaries provide with either *phonemic notation* (in Thai script, but saying exactly how to read — likewise I showed for `พัท-ทะ-ยา`) or IPA or another *phonetic* system. One just needs to learn those exceptions (there are really plenty of those, however).

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory comments. Also, the link you provided in your comment has quite a lot of interesting linguistic technical terminology. Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: As one last thing I was wondering, are all words in the acrophonic system for the letters pronounced exactly as spelled or do these present exceptions as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the descriptive words are pronounced as spelled, just be aware about the lexical tones. E.g., for ก ไก่ `[ko kai]`, the word `[kai]`, "chicken", the tone is low. Don't mix it with the consonant class, these are two totally different things.